# If $n$ is any integer $> 1$ , and $(n-1)! = 1 \mod n$

Tags: group-theory

If $n$ is any integer $> 1$ , and $(n-1)! = 1 \mod n$. Prove $n$ is prime

$(n-1)! = 1 \mod n \implies n | 1 - (n-1)! \implies nk + (n-1)! = 1$, for some integer k. So $nk + 1.(2.3.4...(n-3)(n-2)(n-1)) = 1 \implies (n,1)=1$

Answer (score 2):

$(n-1)! = 1 \mod n \implies (n-1)! = 1+\ell n$ for some integer $\ell$.
Hence $\gcd((n-1)!,n) = 1$ since $(n-1)! = 1+\ell n$ and right hand side $(1+\ell n)$ is not divisible by any prime factor of $n$ So $(n-1)!$ is also not divisible by any prime factor of $n$. Hence $n$ is a prime since otherwise $n$  would have factor among $1,...,n-1$ and $\gcd((n-1)!,n) \neq 1$.